# Setting an image source via Javascript unreliable in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, getelementbyid

I am simply trying to change the `SRC` attribute of an image via javascript like so:

```
document.getElementById('fooImage').src = img;
```

Where `img` is a variable that has a link to the file.

In all other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) this works.  In IE (7+) this also works too ***sometimes***.

Using IE's built-in developer tools, I can see that the image's `SRC` tag is set.  Is there something else in the locals window that could help me debug why the image doesn't actually show on screen?

I've also tried using jQuery to do this and same outcome:

```
$("#fooImage").attr("src", img);
```

An ideas?

Comment: Sounds like it would work, but you could try document.getElementById('fooImage').setAttribute('src',img) just to make sure.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you checked the image's dimensions and file size? I recently had a similar problem where after some bad times I discovered IE simply gives up trying to load images after a certain size is passed. In my case it was some outrageous thing like 44,000 pixels tall. I still don't know if it was file size or image dimensions, but either way it was one of them.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that shows this? Doesn't seem correct. What exactly is `img`? Is it a full url, a relative url or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your responses! @JamesHay that didn't work either .. @KaiQung the picture is 300x608 and the actual size is 115kb .. @mrtsherman, `img` is a relative URL

Comment: @epascarello I don't believe so .. would caching it help?

Comment: What I mean is: do you have a bad/old version of the image/JavaScript code cached? Clear the cache and see if it works.

Comment: I cleared the full cache and it still doesn't work... Is there any part of the IE Dev Tools (or Fiddler) that I can look at to see what may be going wrong?

Comment: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ See what is going out to the server and back.

Comment: Try setting `image.src = ''`, then the actual value.

Comment: @katspaugh, thanks, but unfortunately that returned the same result.  The image is being returned from the server.  It looks like it may be a CSS issue as I've noticed some other elements on the page look off when compared to other browsers.  I'll go line by line through the page and report back soon.  Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

In debugging this I would hard code it first...

```
document.getElementById('fooImage').src = "myimage.png";
```

I've used the following in my website and it works like this...

```
var imgCounter = document.getElementById('formtimer');
imgCounter.src = "graphics/odometers/1.png";
```

**Some other things to check:**

1. Make sure your ID= tag is not in the `<DIV` section but inside the `<IMG` section...  for example `<div class="style1"><img src="yourpicture" id="someid">`.  If `id='someid' is in the div tag then you can't change the picture / the picture won't show up.
2. are you using window.onload?, body onload?  the proper way to use the first is..

   ```
    window.onload = function () { YourFunctionHere(); };
   ```
3. Try a different test image.  I had issues in the past with showing png's, I changed it to a gif or jpg and it worked.  I don't understand how that was "way back" but it doesn't seem to be an issue anymore but hey... something to try.
4. try a full url
5. using https?
6. try sticking the image somewhere else in your program and see what happens.
7. try adding this to your HTML (put your website in place of mine - lookup BASE href on google for more info)

   ```
   <BASE href="http://perrycs/" />
   ```
8. Make sure the image isn't hidden behind a layer (I know it works in some browsers)
9. tell us the website so we can check it out and get more info to help you in debugging this, seeing context (surrounding code) helps...

Answer (score 0):

Given that it works in other browsers, searching on this topic it seems that often the problem is how IE caches images (ref. Epascarello's comment).  Your code is the same as what I have - it works fine except in IE10.

Answer (score 0):

I too, faced this conundrum. Then discovered that it works in 'Page Inspector', so after some digging discovered that (in Internet Explorer) by going to Tools.Internet Options.Advanced
uncheck the 'Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)' and the one below it.

Answer (score 0):

I found that with IE9 after changing an image.src with

`var strVar="C:Users/x/Desktop/caution.png"
image.src=strVar`

and calling an alert(image.src) I would get something like this n the alertbox:

> > file:///C:Users/x/Desktop/"C:Users/x/Desktop/caution.png"

So I tried
`image.src=strVar.replace(/\"/g,"")`
to remove qoutemarks
and it worked!
alert(image.src)

> > file:///C:Users/x/Desktop/caution.png